# make gcs object URL public to all users within an organization

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-iam

I have a bucket **bucket1** in which there is a file **abc.pdf**, I want to make this file accessible by all the users in my organization irrespective of they have GCP account or not i.e., make it specifically public to all my intranet users in my organization who are even not part of GCP also.

for example : if a user with id - abc@xyz.com who is not a part of GCP or doesn't have google account when he clicks the URL he should be able to access it.

need guidance and help on this.

Comment: What's your identity provider?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using [signed URLs](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/signed-urls) as users are provided with time-limited access to a specific Cloud Storage resource even without a Google account.